# has exceeded the 'max_connections_per_hour'

Tags: php, mysql

my hosting pop this kind of error message during a flood of active user using my system online.. "has exceeded the 'max_connections_per_hour'"

Then the server provider said it was my connection code was not optimized.

===========

```
@session_start();

(CONNECTION VARIABLE ON TOP)

$localhost = mysql_pconnect($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 

@mysql_select_db($database_userdb, $localhost);

@error_reporting(0);
```

===============

This was the code originally, then the server provider suggested me to change mysql_pconnect into PDO or mysqli connection

Then we change to this

```
try {

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$hostname_localhost.';dbname='.$database_userdb, $username_localhost, $password_localhost);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

And that error "has exceeded the 'max_connections_per_hour'" still pop up..
And today the server provider suggested me that "the script should be using a persistent MySQL connections.", so am I going to change back the PDO into mysql_pconnect which is persistent MYSQL connection that we use originally..

Both connection works fine on the system, just that with a massive flow of traffic into the system, that error pops up on my web page..

By the way.. im using include("connection.php"); something like this on the page.. does that effect my persistent connection?

And how do I resolve this matter? Please help me..

Comment: 1. You can use persistent connections in PDO with `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT`. 2. If you were already using persistent connections then switching to PDO, while beneficial in a more general sense, is not likely to make a difference. 3. `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated for years, and removed in PHP7. 4. If you're only ever making a single mySQL connection within the context of a page load, *and* you're using persistent connections, then chances are that the amount of traffic that you're serving is why you're running afoul of your limits and you'll have to upgrade your hosting.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing YOLO operator (`@`) obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Comment: You need a connection pool, a better database layer than core PHP can provide, or you need to relax your server settings.